# Datatables - jQuery/Javascript dropdown box contains empty selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have made a dropdown filter for my datatable, as you can see in the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/6k0bshb6/45/) there is an option which contains no data - if you look through inspect element `<option value=""></option>` how can I remove this empty container and tell my datatable function for dropdown boxes to skip appending options to the select option when they are empty.

```
// Dropdown filter function for dataTable from hidden column number 5 for filtering gifts.
       initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns(5).every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value="">Show all</option></select>')
                    .appendTo($("#contracts_control-panel").find("div").eq(1)) // append dropdown to div 2 in control panel
                    .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                    $(this).val());
                    column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                        dataTable.page.len(5).draw(); //reset pagination after dropdown filter change.
                });
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

I tried wrapping an if statement around the append like this...

```
column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
      if (d !== undefined) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      }
            });
```

but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: `d !== ""` rather than `undefined` ? https://jsfiddle.net/6k0bshb6/46/

Comment: that solved it thanks

Comment: added it as an answer as per SO policy. Please accept it if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d !== ""` instead of `d !== undefined`. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k0bshb6/46/).

```
column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
  if (d !== "") {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can modified like this

```
column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
     d&&d.length&&select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
});
```

I found one row lose its value as below:
[image]

Comment: I removed that value in the HTML, this works thanks :) what does the ```j&&``` do can you explain it?

Comment: in fact this seems to break the function

Comment: `d&function(){}` equals `if (d) { select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')}`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of "Show All" like below.

```
<select><option value="Show All">Show all</option><option value=""></option><option value="Free Biscuits">Free Biscuits</option><option value="Free PS4">Free PS4</option><option value="Free TV">Free TV</option><option value="Free XBOX">Free XBOX</option></select>
```

And once the page load is complete, you could use JQuery to remove the empty drop down option. The below option remove the dropdown item based on index

```
$('.dropdown-filter-div option:eq(1)').remove()
```

or use the below JQuery, the below code removes the dropdown item based on value (which is empty in your code)

```
$('.dropdown-filter-div option[value=""]').remove()
```

Hope this helps.